# Virtual Host points to another Virtual Host

Tags: apache, virtual, host, httpd.conf

**HELP!** I just setup a virtual host for two sites that have a lot of traffic and I think I just messed something up! Here is the end of my **httpd.conf**:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.mydomain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/downloadr
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName mydomain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/downloadr
</VirtualHost>
```

I added the last virtual host to solve the problem of mydomain2.com going to wwww.mydomain.com. HOWEVER, what has happened now is that www.mydomain2.com goes to www.mydomain.com.

Please help!!!

Thanks all

### UPDATE

STUPIDITY beyond words - managed to copy one site to two directories and hence the 2 domains pointing to the same place!! OMG this will not happen again. Double check and recheck and recheck and recheck and recheck and recheck........

Btw, why would someone neg rep me for this?

Comment: Can't help with your question directly, but if it's really urgent, you could put a bounty up on it, and you'll probably get a lot of hits more quickly.

Comment: How do I do that? I thought it was only possible after a question wasn't answered after 2 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the third virtual host, add

```
ServerAlias mydomain2.com
```

to the second one. So your entire configuration would be basically this:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.mydomain2.com
    ServerAlias mydomain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/downloadr
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want requests for `mydomain.com` to actually be redirected to `www.mydomain.com`, so that the user sees the URL change in his/her browser, that can be done with `mod_rewrite` (but that's the subject of another question, search for it if you like)

Comment: I have done this too. Did not know it was supposed to be like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having problems with this it turns out that for `ServerName` Apache did not like the www prepended. So it should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName mydomain2.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain2.com *.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www" #WAMP INSTALL
</VirtualHost>
```